# Face recognition for a specific scenario

Tags: face-recognition

My problem:

I have person X that I want to identify

- picture(s) are about 72dpi 200x400
- the face is not the focal point of the image (probably about 10 percent of the image)
- the face is almost always at some angle, from 0-60 degrees off center in any direction
- sometimes I have multiple angles of the same face, very rarely a closeup
- these pictures have varying lighting, too broad to be defined

I have a database of much higher quality pictures to compare against

- sometimes the database has zoomed out pictures, but mostly zoomed into the face and directly at the camera
- this database has about 3000 pictures that come with the identity of certain people

I want to find person X in my database to some degree of certainty.

I realize this requires facial recognition, but there are so many approaches to feature detection/recognition/etc, I'm wondering what the best would be given my scenario.

Comment: [OpenCV has a page on Face Recognition](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FaceRecognition) that might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As the first step you should detect the faces in both you database and you subject images.

Here is an openCV example:
http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html

OpenCV comes with several different classifiers but perhaps you need further effort to detect angled faces.

For a classification of the subject you can use an eigenface implementation. There is also a library for openCV:
https://github.com/bytefish/libfacerec

However, for a classification you also need angled faces in your training data. Otherwise you won't find a good match.

Comment: Lukas, thanks for advertising my work! :) Drop me a mail! By the way, could you please link to: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/index.html instead of libfacerec. As its integrated in there already.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I figured I would post the solution I went with. Face.com was a face detection and recognition REST API that did what I wanted with a lot better results than most of the libraries I tried.

Comment: Yes. Until they shut their API down, which is going to happen soon I heard.

Comment: Yea so I hear. August 8 or something. Yay facebook for making me hate you more!

Comment: So when it was shut down what did you do? You can edit this answer with your chosen library so others will know as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use something like [link to algorithm for detecting Face color](http://onebit.us/x/i/814381733331796005.pdf).  You'll find an algorithm that indicates skin color face recognition.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.